# Disable all css minification with Web Compiler (Visual Studio extension)

Tags: css, visual-studio, less, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

My less files compiles to css on each save, but how do I disable minification for all css files i the project in a simple way? I can see in the docs that it's possible to give each file its own settings. But that's a total pain to configure, since I have hundreds of css files.

This can be done for each file in the `compilerconfig.json`:

```
[
  {
    "outputFile": "output/site.css",
    "inputFile": "input/site.less",
    "minify": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "includeInProject": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "options":{}
  }
]
```

[Web Compiler extension can be found here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3b329021-cd7a-4a01-86fc-714c2d05bb6c)

Comment: link to your extension?

Comment: Added a link to the post

Comment: Yeah, this is bugging me too!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to specify project-wide minification settings yet. I'm planning to add it to the `compilerconfig.json.defaults` file.

Comment: Yes please! Want this off by default.

Comment: @Mads Kvist Kristensen, don't mean to stress. But do you have an ETA on this? =)

Comment: It made in to the latest CI build here http://vsixgallery.com/extension/148ffa77-d70a-407f-892b-9ee542346862/

Comment: @MadsKvistKristensen Can you please update the link or provide the global solution here. Thanks!!!